# TypeError indicates a list error, but no list in code

Tags: python-3.x, graph, typeerror

I am having a problem resolving the TypeError in this piece of code. It keeps saying “TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str” and the funny part is that I do not have a list in the code. I “HAD” a list, but have since changed that to a dict. The line with the error is this:

```
if (link_params.get('bandwidth', 99999) < dist['bandwidth']):
```

I have tried breaking this up in the interpreter and it works fine there. No problems whatsoever.

```
for neighbor, edges in active_graph[curnode].items():
    # We create a hack here for astar since it is not implemented for 
    # multigraphs. If a node has multiple edges to its neighbor,
    # we always pick the first edge in the edge dict. This may cause 
    # unexpected behavior because we are using an unordered dict and the
    # first value may not be the same all the time. Also, in a multigraph,
    # the adjacency list to every neighbor is a dict itself, keyed with the
    # edge identifier. In the case of a single edge, the edge identifier is 0.
    if neighbor in explored:
        continue
    link_params = dict(edges[0])
    if (link_params.get('bandwidth', 99999) < dist['bandwidth']):
        ncost['bandwidth'] = link_params['bandwidth'] 
    else:
        ncost['bandwidth'] = dist['bandwidth']
    ncost['latency'] = dist['latency'] + link_params['latency']
    ncost['cost'] = dist['cost'] + link_params['cost’]
```

**active_graph[node].items()** returns an iterator over the keys and values. I have a triple nested dict here.

First level - adjacency dict.

Second level - edge dict.

Third level - edge attribute dict.

The rationale is that the first level keeps tracks of the neighboring nodes (keyed by the neighbor node ids, the second level stores the edges and the third level stores the edge attributes. This is to aid a multigraph scenario.

For e.g., G[1] will give us the adjacency list for node 1, let us say:

```
{2: {0: {‘a’: 1, ‘b’: 2, ‘c’:3}, 1: {‘d’: 4, ‘e’: 5, ‘f’:6}}}
```

G[1][2] will give us

```
{0: {‘a’: 1, ‘b’: 2, ‘c’:3}, 1: {‘d’: 4, ‘e’: 5, ‘f’:6}}
```

and finally, G[1][2][0] will give us

```
{‘a’: 1, ‘b’: 2, ‘c’:3}
```

where I can query for anything, such as G[1][2][0].get(‘a’, 99). This is what I am doing currently and getting the TypeError. Can someone please point out what I am missing here?

EDIT:

1. Traceback

   File "/src/controlplane/algorithms/astar.py", line 96, in astar_path

   ```
   if (link_params.get('bandwidth', 99999) < dist['bandwidth']):
   TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
   ```
2. No, dist is not a list. It is a dict.

   ```
   ncost = {}
   qcost = {}
   dist = {}
   default_dict_keys = ['bandwidth', 'latency', 'cost']
   for key in default_dict_keys:
       if key == 'bandwidth':
           dist.setdefault(key, 99999)
       else:
           dist.setdefault(key, 0)
       ncost.setdefault(key, 0)
       qcost.setdefault(key, 0)
   ```

Comment: Show us the traceback.

Comment: Where does `dist` come from? It looks like `dist` is a list. Figure out why it's a list, and you'll find your bug.

Comment: If it was a list, try cleaning up precompiled modules.

Comment: @user2357112 - I have edited my post. And no, dist is not a list.

Comment: @Kiwi - I am using Eclipse. How do I do that? I thought closing and re-opening Eclipse would accomplish that.

Comment: Well, you seem to be replacing it with a list at some point. Check all places it could have been switched. It'd help if you tried to [pare your code down to a minimal runnable test case that demonstrates the problem when you run it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), both because it'd help us see what's going on and because the process of stripping the program down often discovers the error.

Comment: @user2357112 - Thanks for that. I did go through my code again and found a set of stray square brackets that left the dict as a dangling list. It was a little hard to find since this was hitting it on the corner case. I will be more careful with the code. :)